# How can I use localstorage with jquery (if-else)

Tags: jquery

I have a  html page and simple jquery codes. I want to add "read/unread" text near a post. When I click unread text it becomes read and click again read text it becomes unread. I want to save my jquery changes. I can change read/unread text but I cant save changes with using localStorage. When I refresh page everytime text becomes "unread". My codes need some restore. These are my codes.Not:I use jinja2 no database no server just local. thanks for time.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>

   $(function() {
    $('h4').on('click', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).text(localStorage.getItem('read'));
        if ($this.text()==="unread"){
           localStorage.setItem('read', 'read');
        }
        else if ($this.text()==="read"){
           localStorage.setItem('read', 'unread');
        }
    });
});
    </script>


    {% for data in collecteddata %}
        <div align="center" class="box">{{ data }}</div><h4>unread</h4>
    {% endfor %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I changed my codes but it still doesnt work :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [setItem()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/#dom-storage-setitem) - to set value and [getItem()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/#dom-storage-getitem) - to read value

```
$(function() {
    var $h4 = $('h4').on('click', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this), text = $.trim($this.text());
        if (text === "unread"){
            localStorage.setItem('read', 'read');
        } else if (text === "read"){
            localStorage.setItem('read', 'unread');
        }
        $(this).text(localStorage.getItem('read'));
    });

    var text = localStorage.getItem('read');
    if(text){
        $h4.text(text);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vUyze/)

Comment: thank you very much but there is  little problem. I have posts and every post has a text(unread) (near the post title). when I click one of them to do "read" and refresh the page every post's "unread" becomes read.

Comment: @ReneeWalker then you need to store the data using the post id... or some other identifier otherwise we cannot distinguish which one was read

Comment: Actually these are not posts. I use jinja2 and render some data. For example I render list items and write a html page. How can I use identifier?

Comment: @ReneeWalker the identifier has to be decided by the server... i don't know anything about the server side technology used here... the server should always give the same id to a particular post always...

Answer (score 1):

Use [setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) like

```
$(this).text(localStorage.getItem('read'));
if ($this.text()==="unread"){
    localStorage.setItem('read','read');
}
else if ($this.text()==="read"){
    localStorage.setItem('read','unread');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Local storage work as key:value pair. Here are the basics:- 
e.g.;

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");  // to store value in, by unique key
var value = localStorage.getItem("key"); // retreive value by key name
```